# facebook graph api search permission

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I try to search using graph api and get error message
 Application does not have the capability to make this API call.

What are the needed permissions and how to get them

```
FB.api(
              "/search",
            {
                access_token:'XXXXXXXXXX',
                "type": "topic",
                "q": "San Francisco Events",
                "fields": "id,name,page"
            },
            function (response) {
                if (response && !response.error) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
                else
                {
                    console.log("Error");
                    console.log(response);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

Topic search isn't publicly available, that's why it is listed under "Media Solutions" in the Graph API docs. Afaik it's currently not possible to apply for it.